# OAuth + Google Calendar + Python

Tags: python, oauth, calendar, passwords

I'm stuck..

Basically my goal is I want to be able to pull in end user's calendars, and parse their data daily. I don't need any interaction from them, just enough to authenticate them with OAuth. My current solution is a plain text file that it goes through as a dictionary and pulls in the calendar that way, but that's just asking for trouble. I am just getting my hands on OAuth but don't know how I'd use it in my instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-oauth2-tool-python/blob/master/gs-oauth.py) for using OAuth2 to access Google Cloud Storage.  You should be able to use it with relatively small tweaks to pull Google Calendar data (primarily changing the scope from `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`

[This example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/plus/plus.py) is also helpful, showing how to loop over all a user's Google+ activities and print them to the console.  Especially take note of how to use `from apiclient.discovery import build` to build an API object to interacte with the service.

You can also play with the Google Calendar API using the [OAuth 2.0 playground tool](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) or look through the API using the [APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/).